# Upgrade from 3.5.x to the Latest

Tags: rabbitmq

Since 3.5.x and the latest version require different versions of Erlang. What is the best way to upgrade?

v3.7.7 needs Erlang 21.0.x while 3.5.5 is on 17.5.x but since RabbitMQ uses ERLANG_HOME to figure out where Erlang is. How can I have both versions running? I can't simply take down the current version to upgrade since it's our production environment.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The best way is to have a testing environment. But either way, this question is off topic. Stack Overflow is about programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommended approach is to set up a new cluster and migrate producers and consumers to it.
To ensure that no data is lost during the migration, you can use Federation.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/blue-green-upgrade.html
https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/Upgrading-RabbitMQ-with-zero-downtime